# Prevent window resize during QStatusBar resize

Tags: c++, qt, resize, qstatusbar

If application's main window has `QStatusBar` and if it's width becomes bigger (for example during adding a widget) than the main window's width, the window automatically resizes to fit status bar. I wonder is there way to prevent window's size changes in such cases?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a way out of this situation. I added a `QScrollArea` to my status bar and now I add my widgets to that scroll area, so they do not affect on main window's size.

Answer (score 0):

To do that I would write a little [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) resize blocker like this:

```
class ResizeBlocker
{ 
public:
    ResizeBlocker(QWidget *widget)
        : m_widget(widget)
    {
        m_widget->setFixedSize(m_widget->size());
    }

    ~ResizeBlocker()
    {
        m_widget->setFixedSize(QSize(QWIDGETSIZE_MAX, QWIDGETSIZE_MAX));
    }

private:
    QWidget *m_widget;
};
```

Which can be used something like this:

```
void MainWindow::addToStatusBar()
{
    ResizeBlocker doNotResizeHere(this);
    ui->statusBar->addWidget(new QLabel("A Label"));
}
```

I've created a demo of this and uploaded it to GitHub [here](https://github.com/peterSW/QResizeBlocker).

Comment: @nabroyan In what way doesn't it work? A compiler error, or the window still resizes? Could you show what you tried?

Comment: It compiles and runs, but window still resizes. I've just copy-pasted your code and passed the pointer of my main window.

Comment: Are you using it within the scope that contains the call that triggers the resize?
In my example it only blocks the resize with in the addToStatusBar() function, so that the user can still resize the window.

Comment: Yes, I create a `ResizeBlocker` class object right before `addWidget()` function call

Comment: Well, it turned out, that it resizes, but when widgets are being removed and when user tries to resize window it returns to it's original size.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49353/discussion-between-petersw-and-nabroyan)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to fix it by simply setting a fixed size for the widget that I added to the status bar